Spreadsheets select rows from another sheet dynamically with sheet name also in query
I have this query
    =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A1&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A1&"!C2:C")<>"", A1, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A2&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A2&"!C2:C")<>"", A2, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A3&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A3&"!C2:C")<>"", A3, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A4&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A4&"!C2:C")<>"", A4, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A5&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A5&"!C2:C")<>"", A5, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A6&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A6&"!C2:C")<>"", A6, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A7&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A7&"!C2:C")<>"", A7, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A8&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A8&"!C2:C")<>"", A8, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A9&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A9&"!C2:C")<>"", A9, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A10&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A10&"!C2:C")<>"", A10, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A11&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A11&"!C2:C")<>"", A11, "")}, {"","","",""}); 
IFERROR({INDIRECT(A12&"!C2:E"), IF(INDIRECT(A12&"!C2:C")<>"", A12, "")}, {"","","",""})
}, "select Col4, Col1, Col2 where Col3 contains 'AutoService'", 0)) 

which returns the following error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.
This is because I don't have yet created last 3 sheets


Basically I want to select 3 columns from 12 various sheets with name of the month. Also I want to include name of the month rows are from.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

thanks for idea. here it is.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dWQf_CUnWmXA1rsykJr8VP3juAmdz6cm-GXW2emuzns/edit


Here's one alternative approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1), reduce(Σ,tocol(A1:A12,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserr(+a),Σ,a),let(Λ,filter(iferror(indirect(c&"!C2:D"),iferror(now()/0)),regexmatch(indirect(c&"!E2:E"),"(?i)autoservice")),if(iserror(Λ),Σ,hstack(wrapcols(c,rows(Λ),c),Λ)))))))


IMPORTANT: When a new tab (say Apr) is created, indirect() in this scenario does not automatically pick up this new tab data for consideration. To prompt for consideration instantly, make some kind of edit/change anywhere in the sheet; it could be as simple as ticking a checkbox or entering 1 in a cell for example...

Man! thanks. It works. However is so complex to understand! But it works. Could you also please now how could I make a sum of column with price?
